# Evaluating Run Time of Algorithm to Determine if Tree is Balanced

Tags: algorithm, tree

```
public static int getHeight(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return -1;
    return Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right)) + 1;
}

public static boolean isBalanced(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return true;

    int heightDiff = getHeight(root.left) - getHeight(root.right);
    if (Math.abs(heightDiff) > 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
    }
}
```

The above algorithm is stated as O(N log N).

Why is it not O(n^2)?

`isBalanced` traverses every node which is O(N) and `getHeight` also traverses each node which is O(N).

Source [Cracking the Coding Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984782850)

Comment: Your `getHeight` function always returns -1. I think you're missing a +1 in there.

Comment: You're correct, fixed.

Comment: When the tree is balanced, the `getHeight()` call made from the root traverses all `N` nodes.  All the calls made from depth 1, taken together, traverse all nodes with depth >=1 -- O(N) again.  at worst there are O(log N) levels and the `getHeight()` calls traverse O(N) calls from each level, so O(N log N) all together.   I'm not writing this as an answer, because I don't feel like proving that the balanced tree is indeed the worst case :)

Comment: In `getHeight()`: We are not eliminating any of the space by divide and conquer here. I think it should be O(n) regardless of the shape of tree. Check [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-find-the-maximum-depth-or-height-of-a-tree/) too.

Comment: Arash, thank you for your answer and time with the comments on your now-deleted post. Seeing that `getHeight` is O(n) and isBalanced is also O(n), why is this algorithm as a whole considered O(N Log N) and not O(N^2)?

Comment: Let's assume that the heights are precalculated and available in every node. We still need to recursively call `isBalanced` on every node, which is O(n). I think O(n^2) should be the answer. I would try to look it up in other resources...

Comment: Perhaps O(n^2) is too loose because for each node, it only touches the nodes under it. So the first node would touch n nodes, then when it traversed to the 2nd level it would touch n/2 nodes, etc. Perhaps this is where the O(N log N) comes from?

Comment: Yes. I think so. I was looking for CLRS and this [picture](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/Gifs/img1A.gif) in particular. Basically the amount of work in each level is still `cn` (c depends on the problem that we are solving) and the height of tree is `log(n)` ==> we get O(n log n)